# CEFSharp 105, with proprietary codecs

Tags: h.264, cefsharp, codec, chromium-embedded

I am trying to build CEF 105 with proprietary codecs. I can do the build following the master build page but it doesn't look to create the necessary output files to copy across to my CEFsharp Winforms application. Specifically, missing the SwiftShader folder as an example. I tried as both a component build and official build, but still the same.

My update.bat is:

```
set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true use_thin_lto=false proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2019 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
python ..\automate\automate-git.py --download-dir=c:\code\chromium_git --branch=5195 --depot-tools-dir=c:\code\depot_tools --no-distrib --no-build
```

My create.bat is:

```
set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true use_thin_lto=false proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
set GYP_DEFINES=buildtype=offical
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2019 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
call cef_create_projects.bat
```

Then I run ninja with:

```
ninja -C out\Release_GN_x64 cef
```

Anyone any ideas what I am doing wrong? I'm sure it worked fine like this in a previous version of CEF.

Answer (score 0):

Swiftshader has been removed, it was deprecated some time ago and stopped being shipped in M102.

Also component builds are only for local debugging, you need an official build.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the swiftshader folder is still created though with the libEGL and libGLESv2.dll in it with CEFSharp 105. Are you able to say which files needed to be copied over to the x64 folder please?

Comment: Have you tested with an official release from Nuget.org? CEF doesn't build the files anymore so it's not possible for them to be included. The script to package CEF was updated in commit https://github.com/cefsharp/cef-binary/commit/0dd29533e4b65ef38b5707afd610ace53cab4feb You can review https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-%28Redistribution%29 for a list of files.